# Fetch and merge observable array of responses

Tags: typescript, rxjs

For each value in an observable array, fetch an array of numbers, merging all results together into a single observable array of numbers.

I've tried various combinations of `flatMap` and `concatMap` but can't get it right.

```
someFunction(): Observable<number[]> {
  // Observable<string[]>
  const strings = of(['a', 'b', 'c']);

  let index = 0;

  // Observable<number[]>
  const numbers = strings.pipe(
    flatMap(ids => ids.map(() => of([index++, index++, index++])))
  );

  return numbers; // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, it seems that `bars` Observable emits an instance of type `Bar[]` as the consequence of the Observable `fooIds` emitting an array of ids.

If this is the case, there are  probably 2 things to be noticed here.

The first one is the use of `switchMap`. With this operator you complete any observable which is on-fly as soon as another emission in source observable occurs.

In other words, if `fooIds` emits 2 arrays of ids in a very fast sequence, or synchronously for that matter, so that `bars` has not completed processing the first array of ids when the second arrives, than the first one is ignored and only the second one is processed. If you want to preserve all results, you may want to consider to use `mergeMap` (a.k.a. `flatMap`) rather than `switchMap`.

The second thing is the use of `concatAll`. With this operator, you want to preserve the sequence of the source observable. The resulting Observable will always emit  single instance of type `bar[]` containing all `bars` retrieved using the ids passed by one single notification of `fooIds`.

If the result you want to achieve is one single array of `Bar` containing all items coming from all notifications of `fooIds` you may consider to use `reduce` operator, e.g. in the following way

```
reduce((acc, one: any) => {
    acc = acc.concat(one);
    return acc;
}, []),
```

**UPDATED ANSWER after comment of @hdk**

This should be the code that make you example work

```
function someFunction(): Observable<number[]> {
    // Observable<string[]>
    const strings = of(['a', 'b', 'c']);

    let index = 0;

    // Observable<number[]>
    const numbers = strings.pipe(
      mergeMap(ids => ids.map(() => of([index++, index++, index++]))),
      mergeMap(d => d)  // flattens the Observable<Observable<number>> to Observable<number>
    );

    const numbersReduced = numbers
    .pipe(
        reduce((acc: Array<number>, one: Array<number>) => {
            acc = acc.concat(one);
            return acc;
        }, new Array<number>()),
    ); 

    return numbersReduced// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
}

someFunction().subscribe(console.log)
```

The key is to recognize that

```
mergeMap(ids => ids.map(() => of([index++, index++, index++])))
```

returns an `Observable<Observable<number>>`.

Why? Because `ids.map(....)` returns an `Array`, which is an `ObservableInput`. `mergeMap` requires as input a function which returns an `ObservableInput` so a function that returns an `Array` would suffice. If then that `Array`, as in this case, contains itself other Observables, then you get exactly the `Observable<Observable<number>>` return type which we are witnessing.

The rest should be more or less straightforward.

In real world, e.g. if you are dealing with http requests, you could use other strategies, such as for instance use `forkJoin`. This is how the code would look like in such case

```
function someFunction(): Observable<number[]> {
    // Observable<string[]>
    const strings = of(['a', 'b', 'c']);

    let index = 0;

    const numbers = strings.pipe(
        mergeMap(ids => {
            const numberObservables = ids.map(() => of([index++, index++, index++]));
            return forkJoin(numberObservables)
        })
    );

    const numbersReduced = numbers
    .pipe(
        map(arrayOfArrayOfNumbers => arrayOfArrayOfNumbers
            .reduce(
                (acc: Array<number>, one: Array<number>) => {
                    acc = acc.concat(one);
                    return acc;
                }, new Array<number>()
            ))
    )

    return numbersReduced// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
}
```

Notice that you are still using `reduce` but, this time, it is the `Array` `reduce` method and not the `Observable` `reduce` method we have used in the previous case.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Reduce should be the right approach but I still couldn't get it right.

Comment: I have updated my answer based on your comment and the edited version of your question